# addClass not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

Here is my code. I want to toggle classes using `addClass`,for some reasons I don't want to use `toggleClass`. Problem here I am facing is that css class named `selected` is added but its not replaced by `not_selected`.`isSelected=0` only indicates that `td` is selected or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


var isSelected = 0;

$("td").click(function(){
    if(isSelected==0)
    {
        $(this).removeClass('not_selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        isSelected=1;
    }

});

$("td").click(function(){
    if(isSelected==1)
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('not_selected');
        isSelected=0;
    }
});
```

Below is my `css` code:

```
.selected
{
    background: black;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.not_selected
{
    background: white;
    color:black;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Why are you attaching 2 listeners to the same event (click)?

Comment: The problem is that you're using two handlers. Both of them run, and the second one undoes the effect of the first.

Comment: Take a look at [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try condensing the two into a single function. It's <strike>possible</strike> guaranteed (thanks Barmar!) that one handler is running before the other and then automatically switching it back to the undesired one. This way, it will check for `isSelected==0` and `isSelected==1` in one swoop.

```
$("td").click(function(){
    if(isSelected==0)
    {
        $(this).removeClass('not_selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        isSelected=1;
    } else if(isSelected==1)
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('not_selected');
        isSelected=0;
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need the second `if`, just use `else`, since 0 and 1 are the only possibilities.

Comment: It's not just possible, it's guaranteed that one handler runs before the other, since Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: I'm leaving room for the possibility that there's some kind of error checking Labeeb wants to do at the end with a final `else` clause, but if the snippet is all there is, you're right.

Comment: I'd actually switch from 1/0 to true/false.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/NYGh5/

The problem is your event handler

```
$("td").click(function(){
    if(isSelected==0)
    {
        $(this).removeClass('not_selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        isSelected=1;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('not_selected');
        isSelected=0;
    }
});
```

You should do the whole work in one callback function. not in two. Otherwise the functions are enabling/disabling each other.